# ContentDocumentLink query not working with dynamic Id

Tags: apex, trigger, contentdocumentlink

Im trying to querry the ContentDocumentLink object and althogh I have a ContentDocumentId with a valid ID it wont populate the querry.

```
for(ContentDocument cd: newList){
    derp = cd.id;
    }
    system.debug('los ids'+derp);
    system.debug('map'+newMap.get( derp ).ID);
    Set<Id> newSet = newMap.keySet();
    list<ContentDocumentLink> cdls = [SELECT Id, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId, LinkedEntity.type  from ContentDocumentLink where  ContentDocumentId in:newSet];
      system.debug('CDL'+newSet);
        system.debug('CDL'+cdls);
```

[image]

Comment: When I execute the anonymous window with the hardcoded Id it does populate the querry.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications rather than posting them in the comments.

Comment: The code is looking broken; only the very last ContentDocument's ID will be kept and used in the `newMap.get` because you iterate all documents and assign all their IDs to one string/Id variable `derp` one after another. If you fix that in a trivial way, you'll then have a query in a loop. You need to restructure how you do your querying.

Comment: (Also the execution log doesn't match the sample code making it basically irrelevant)